# AWS Code Commit as alternative to Artifactory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, repository

I can see that AWS Code Commit is an alternative to github/gitlab/stash etc. The product page states:

```
Store Anything
--------------
AWS CodeCommit allows you to store any type of file, and there are no repository
size limits. This allows you to store and version application assets, like images
and libraries, along with your code.
```

Does this mean I could use code commit as an alternative to Artifactory, i.e. as a maven-like repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> AWS CodeCommit is a fully-managed source control service

Which means it is intended for sources. Here are some reasons why a source control is a poor choice for binaries:

- First and foremost – a version control system (VCS) is not a Maven repository! It can’t calculate Maven indexes.
- Versioning mismatch. Source files are versioned by their content. VCSs know how to differentiate them and understand what changed. Binaries, on the other side, are usually versioned by their name. From the VCS point of view, they are different entries, each one without any version history.
- Not sure if CodeCommit can obliterate files. If (like Subversion) it can’t, once a file is added, it stays in the repository forever.
- Source control knows how to search sources. And, of course, the most important type of search is by content. However, searching for binaries is different: what matters most is the file metadata, the location, structure of the file name and, in case of archived artifact, the contents of the archive.
- The permissions scheme of VCSs is tailored for versioning sources (again!). For example, there is no override permission. That’s because overriding sources is something we do all the time in VCS – it’s the same security level as, let’s say, adding a new source file. However, the situation is very different with binaries. While adding new binaries is fine, overriding released binary is something that shouldn’t be done (one should have a special permission for it).